# SQL Server, Select from dateadd of existing date variable

Tags: sql-server, date, dateadd

I am joining 2 tables that both have some date columns. table2 has columns First_Date and Last_Date, table1 has many distinct dates for each of the index column. I want to join them where table1 dates is around 10 days before and after of First_Date or 10 days before and after of Last_Date. 
I have something like this:

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.index=table2.index
where table1.dates between dateadd(day, 10, table2.First_Date) and
dateadd(day, -10, table2.First_Date) or table1.dates between 
dateadd(day,  10, table2.Last_Date) and
dateadd(day, -10, table2.Last_Date)
```

I had no output from that code, I guess SQL is confused by the dateadd, since for each index the First_Date and Last_Date is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL can be confused from the `AND` and the `OR`, try adding brackets.

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.index=table2.index
where (table1.dates between dateadd(day, 10, table2.First_Date) and
dateadd(day, -10, table2.First_Date)) or (table1.dates between 
dateadd(day,  10, table2.Last_Date) and
dateadd(day, -10, table2.Last_Date))
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I also realized the date vs. datetime issue in dateadd() function that made the code not work.